# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread issue

Tags: java, android

Newbie here, I'm making a VERY simple app as explained below :

`MainActivity` has six image buttons, each button goes to its own activity, I gave each image button an image with all different `densities`, also the `MainActivity` has a background image, that is all.Now the problem is, whenever I press any of the buttons, the issue in the title appears, I need to wait for more than 5 seconds for the image button to respond... each of the six activities are empty, I dont have any code/design in them yet (except disabling the status and action bars)...

ps. the app (`MainActivity`) opens normally without any lag or any other issues

`MainActivity` code:

```
package com.example.isaaxmac.school;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}

public void buttonOneClicked(View view) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, OneActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void buttonTwoClicked(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void buttonThreeClicked(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ThreeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void buttonFourClicked(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, FourActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void buttonFiveClicked(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, FiveActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void buttonSixClicked(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SixActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

}
```

Comment: xml and full activity code?

Comment: `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread` then do the **task in the background thread**

Comment: So, you're waiting for 5 seconds using Thread.sleep()? That would be blocking the main thread, so @Maven is spot on. Maybe Handler#postDelayed helps.

Comment: Which library you are using to show images..in all buttons and also in background..?

Answer (score 1):

Too must work on Main Thread means you are blocking your Main UI, try to `finish()` activity after going to new activity(as much I can see from your code):

```
public void buttonOneClicked(View view) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, OneActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

after each `Activity`.

Or else do work on another thread and provide full code.